# angularJS: ui-select form validates on clicking a button other than SUBMIT button

Tags: forms, angularjs, angular-ui

I am relatively new to angularJS. Here is my HTML code:

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="submitForm(form.$valid)" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group col-md-offset-6" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : form.modelOwner.selected.$invalid && !form.modelOwner.selected.$pristine }">
    <div class="input-group select2-bootstrap-append">

      <ui-select ng-model="modelOwner.selected" theme="select2" class="form-control" required>
        <match placeholder="Select Owner">{{$select.selected.ownerName}}</match>
        <choices repeat="item in owner | filter: $select.search">
          <span ng-bind-html="item.ownerName | highlight: $select.search"></span>
        </choices>
      </ui-select>

      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button ng-click="modelOwner.selected = undefined" class="btn btn-danger">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
        </button>
      </span>
      <span ng-show="form.modelOwner.selected.$invalid && !form.modelOwner.selected.$pristine" class="control-label">* Select owner.</span>
    </div>    
  </div>
</form>
```

My JS code is:

```
$scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {

  if (isValid) {
    alert('our form is amazing');
  }
  else{
    alert('our form is not valid');
  }

};
```

Now, the "SUBMIT" button is disabled until the form is valid.

But, when i click on the "CLEAR" button beside my select dropdown, form gets submitted and the error alert message (our form is not valid) is displayed.

The CLEAR button is to remove any drop-down values selected.

I can't figure the reason for this strange behaviour. Please help!

Comment: Can't see the clear button on the code you provided?

Comment: <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button ng-click="modelOwner.selected = undefined" class="btn btn-danger">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
        </button>
      </span>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `type` attribute of your clear button to `button`.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="clear()"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
```

```
$scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.country.selected = undefined;     
  };
```

```
<ui-select ng-model="country.selected" theme="selectize" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a country in the list...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="country in countries | filter: $select.search">
      <span ng-bind-html="country.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
      <small ng-bind-html="country.code | highlight: $select.search"></small>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```